# Can not change permissions while root

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, root, kali-linux

I use Kali Linux and discovered the following "problem":

```
root@kali:/proc/self# ls -l cmdline
-r--r--r-- l root root 0 May 27 13:43 cmdline
root@kali:/proc/self# chmod 744 cmdline
chmod: changing permissions of `cmdline': Operation not permitted
```

I am not allowed to change the permissions of that file... but I am root? Why is that? Are there ways to work around this? I allready tried some things like moving the file (what is obviously not possible), change the runlevel etc.

Answer (score 1):

`/proc` is pseudo-filesystem. In general it is not designated to allow user to `chmod` or `mv` its entries.

More info [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

> The proc filesystem is a pseudo-filesystem which provides an interface to kernel data structures.  It is commonly mounted at `/proc`.  Most of it is read-only, but some files allow kernel variables to be changed.

Comment: ah ok, that explains it. But a program needs to copy this file, do you know any way around?

Comment: `cp cmdline ~/foo` -- should work as you can read the file. Have in mind that `/proc/self` is special, it refers to a program that accesses it. There is difference between `cd /proc/self ; cat cmdline` and `cat /proc/self/cmdline`. Try it.

Comment: Yes your right. But i still got the problem that the program is not mine and allready compiled... so its more of a softwarebug i guess

Comment: @licklake What program? Maybe we have [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) here.

Comment: a metasploit function to pentest ftp servers